# Problems with FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I started off on a different issue which led me here, so ill just start from the beginning. I have an app that allows the user to create quotes for their customers. The app creates a pdf for the quote and saves it to external storage specifically so that other apps can access it. Recently it seems that I am unable to view the pdf in certain apps when opened from within my app (google pdf viewer, google drive viewer show a blank screen while adobe acrobat is perfectly fine). I know the pdf is fine, because I can view it from a file manager without any issues. Its just when opening it from my app that it doesnt work.

I was providing an intent with the uri similar to `content://path/to/external/storage/MyApp/customerName/quote.pdf`

I used to provide it as `file://...` but ran into the exposed uri exception introduced in sdk 24, so i simply renamed file:// to content:// and all seemed to be working until i found out about the google pdf viewer apps.

Now I'm assuming that it has something to do with the fileProvider class that I apparently should have been using. But i cannot seem to get it working at all and none of the other questions Ive found regarding the issue seem to be working, so here is what i have at the moment:

file_paths.xml (was trying a few different paths, none seem to be working. also there are multiple customer folders created by the user, i cannot specify them in the xml file since i dont know what they will be named, but for testing i threw one in there just to see if that was the issue and it still doesn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
     <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
     <external-path name="myApp" path="MyApp/" />
     <external-path name="myAppa" path="MyApp/customerFolder/" />
     <external-path name="myAppb" path="/" />
 </paths>
```

Manifest file (there is a file provider used by one of the includes which is why I have the tools:replace lines in there, I dont know if this is causing a problem or not, it is used to save photos to the same directory im trying to view the pdfs from)

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="authorities"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource"/>
    </provider>
```

And the page that launches the intent to view the pdf:

```
String url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf";
File mFile = new File(url);
Uri pdfURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", mFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(pdfURI);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);                         
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

this has been giving me the following error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf`
on the line that contains `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` method. Ive checked the path and it is correct,

**Alternatively**, this is the code that I used to have, It works for Adobe Acrobat but not Google pdf viewer or google drive viewer. If there is some way of fixing this that I am missing then I can forget about the fileProvider:

```
String url = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ? "content://" : "file://") + "/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url),"application/pdf");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> i simply renamed file:// to content:// and all seemed to be working until i found out about the google pdf viewer apps.

That should work on zero devices. Probably Adobe tries to fix broken input like this.

```
String url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf";
File mFile = new File(url);
```

`file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf` is not a filesystem path. That is a URL. For your experiments, use `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf`. And, eventually, do not hardcode paths.

The `<external-path name="myApp" path="MyApp/" />` element would cover that particular filesystem path.

Comment: i wrote out the url just so i could see what the actual path is, I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` normally. But after removing `file://` and just using `/storage/emulated/...` I seem to be a step closer, its creating a url of `content://com.com.MyApp.provider/myApp/customerFolder/quote.pdf` but none of the pdf viewers are opening it, they give errors like "no File Received" or cant open file.

Comment: The file is there, and using the external_files path gave a different url but the same result. I feel like this is similar to what was happening before. The pdf apps are at least giving me errors now, but adobe doesn't work at all.

Comment: @JStephen: That's odd. Usually, I would expect that behavior if you missed `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, but you have it. [This sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) works, though I integrate a fix to help improve `FileProvider` compatibility with poorly-written client apps.

Comment: I checked your sample app and it is using files from internal storage via `getFilesDir()`, the problem is my files are stored in external storage via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` I was able to copy my file from external to internal storage and then open using the internal file. But ideally I should be able to open the pdf using its external link.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out. Based on CommonsWare's sample app I got it working by copying the file to internal storage and using that internal storage url, but it still would not work using that same file's external storage url. That led me to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538664/cant-action-view-a-file-on-external-storage) where apparently `setType()` will clear out the data set by `setData()`. However, that was not the case when using the internal url, but I tried it anyway, changed this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(pdfURI);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(pdfURI,"application/pdf");
```

and suddenly it worked with the external url as well. A very frustrating inconsistency, especially in my case since I originally had it right but split it into two methods thinking that if one of them went wrong I'd know by the line number.

My manifest stayed the same, but i reduced my paths file to just this

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" />
</paths>
```

hopefully this helps someone else.